# Given an LLVM Instruction, how can we obtain the pointer to its BasicBlock?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Suppose I have an llvm::Instruction* inst, how can I obtain the pointer to its basicblock? I searched in LLVM API and have found no such interface such like inst.getBasicBlock(). Any help?

Answer (score 11):

In well formed LLVM  IR each Instruction is embedded in a `BasicBlock`. You can get the `BasicBlock` from `getParent()`. 
`getParent()` will always go one step up in the LLVM IR hierarchy, i.e., you get a `Function` as parent from a `BasicBlock`, and the `Module` from a `Function`.

Comment: Do keep in mind that getParent() can return NULL if a BasicBlock or an Instruction are either pulled out or constructed without a basic block and before insertion.